Why will VS Code remove the incoming/outgoing changes graph? (circa v1.92-1.93)
I don't really know where this blongs, so part of the question is actually where do you think I should ask this.
I did a little digging in the vscode repo (BTW, to change branch base for vscode its git config --local branch.develop.vscode-merge-base origin/master to change to origin/master), and found this commit by @lszomoru to delete the incoming/outgoing graph from the source-control view.
I think this graph is really nice to have. I just wanted to ask why deleting this nice feature.
Anyway, thank you @lszomoru for all your work.

The way this is worded, its not really appropriate to answer here.  You should just ask on the VS Code repository.  But, if this was worded something like "Is there a way to still show the graph after its removed" or "how do I show the graph after this commit that removed it", my answer here essentially would answer that https://stackoverflow.com/a/78949158/6530134

you know you can comment on the PR for that commit, right? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/226241. also, what makes you think this is a future thing? the PR is merged, and in the August 2024 milestone, which has already been released.

Thank you TimothyG. and starball for your comments.
Hopefully this new view will improve the user experience (and I'll improve my questions' quality (: ).

It's been moved in v1.93 to a dedicated view called "Source Control Graph". See the release notes. The change was made based on user feedback.
